# How to string format subprocess output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my nslookup result using `subprocess` module in Python.

```
b'Server:  server.internal\r\nAddress:  192.168.0.2\r\n\r\nName:    
www.google.com\r\nAddresses:  2404:6800:4007:800::2004\r\n\t  
216.58.197.68\r\n\r\n'
```

Could someone please help me to format the result as below.

```
Server: server.internal
Name: www.google.com
DNS:  192.168.0.2
Addresses: 2404:6800:4007:800::2004 , 216.58.197.68
```

Comment: Use `print` to print \n as a newline.

Comment: You have try for yourself first. Tell us what you tried and what's not working. This isn't a difficult problem if you look for a few minutes on the internet.

Comment: Pass `universalnewlines=True` to the `subprocess.Popen`  (or equivalent helper function like `run`, `check_output`, etc.). That will fix 99% of your issues right there (maybe more; your pasted `bytes` literal is invalid, so you may have added newlines that aren't there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by parsing the lines of the nslookup result into a dictionary, and then using it to format the output.

```
nslookup = (b'Server:  server.internal\r\nAddress:  192.168.0.2\r\n\r\n'
            b'Name: www.google.com\r\nAddresses:  2404:6800:4007:800::2004\r\n'
            b'\t216.58.197.68\r\n\r\n')

info = {}
for line in nslookup.decode().splitlines():
    tokens = line.split()
    if len(tokens) == 2:
        if tokens[0] == 'Addresses:':
            info.setdefault('Addresses', []).append(tokens[1])  # Without ":"
        else:
            info[tokens[0].rstrip(':')] = tokens[1]
    elif len(tokens) == 1:
        info['Addresses'].append(tokens[0])

info['Addresses'] = ', '.join(info['Addresses'])  # Format and convert to string.

print('''\
Server: {Server}
Name: {Name}
DNS:  {Address}
Addresses: {Addresses}'''.format(**info))
```

Output:

```
Server: server.internal
Name: www.google.com
DNS:  192.168.0.2
Addresses: 2404:6800:4007:800::2004, 216.58.197.68
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's `unicode_escape` to help convert it. The result could then be split into lines and reassembled as follows:

```
nslookup = b'Server:  server.internal\r\nAddress:  192.168.0.2\r\n\r\nName: www.google.com\r\nAddresses:  2404:6800:4007:800::2004\r\n\t216.58.197.68\r\n\r\n'
lines = [line.strip('\t').replace('  ', ' ') for line in nslookup.decode('unicode_escape').splitlines()]
print('\n'.join([lines[0], lines[3], lines[1], '{} , {}'.format(lines[4], lines[5])]))
```

Giving you:

```
Server: server.internal
Name: www.google.com
Address: 192.168.0.2
Addresses: 2404:6800:4007:800::2004 , 216.58.197.68
```

`Address:` could be replaced by `DNS:` by a final `.replace()`